# System.Magic.GetAssociatedLayer3Or4Headers(theSocket)?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, header

Is there some method to extract the IP, TCP or UDP header associated with a received packet/telegram.

(an example use-case is finding the TCP sequence number associated with the received byte[])

Note that the socket is just a normal one (not a raw socket) but we want to extract some lower-layer information regarding the received packet. Is it possible?

Comment: For what purpose? The TCP sequence number can't be used in any other way. It is meaningless outside its own context. You'd be better off, surely, just keeping track of the current byte count read from the stream.

Comment: @EJP: This may be interesting, for example, when you log the communication to a file. In this way logging the transmit seq# and ack-seq# along with Message bytes would give a better look if reading the log file and you can see which Message might be in response of which other one.

Comment: The only thing that would be useful for is ACKS. Not messages.

Comment: @EJP: Well, yes, that is exactly what I mean. A given log-file line may say something like:[Time=11:04:01 - Seq = 123456 - Ack = 9876541 - Data = AA-55-41-43] while another line may say [Time=11:04:02 - Seq = 9876542 - Ack = 123456 - Data = FF-01-02-03]. You see I want those two numbers to add into my log-file in addition to the time and data bytes [which currently I have]